# How to change check box border color via programmatically in android?

Tags: android

In my XML contains one `CheckBox`. How to change check box border color via programmatically in android.

My Sample ScreenShot is here
[ScreenShot](http://0prlra.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pDwsdCkcNQqbb_Ut3y4-71FZ9d21K-BrKa2MIVSMpkq7ZENj23MWl9JLLQYShM1Ik5mxS-k8aug1frYjW-I4S0Q/checkbox-css.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set

```
check.setButtonDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.radio));
```

in `radio.xml` you can set any background to your check box.

in radio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/option_unselected" android:state_checked="false"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/option_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
 </selector>
```

here option_selected and option_selected are the graphics for selected and unslected state.

for more you can check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Ya fine. It's used to changing with the tickmark. I need to change with the square check box boreder color ( outline of the Check box Color) .

Comment: You can make option_unselected and option_selected design according to your requirements.

Comment: Mohsin Read my question now. I added a link.

Comment: You can not do this without adding new graphics. There's is no way that you can only change the border color.