# Get Button Drawable CheckBox Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-checkbox

I have multiples `CheckBox`.

I've set a selector for normal and pressed states.
In my app I'll have a dynamic color and i want change the color according to the user's selection, there is a way to change the color for a `CheckBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change CheckBoxs drawable using android:button="@drawable/your_check_drawable" attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This is possible programatically?

Comment: you can set check.setButtonDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.radio));

Comment: Ok, I can't get the assigned drawable right? i have to replace it with another drawable... Thanks alot

Comment: Replace the drawable with a custom xml one. No problem!
Refferance : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288843/how-to-change-check-box-border-color-via-programmatically-in-android