# How to set checkbox border color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-checkbox

The checkbox border is invisible on white background.

[image]

I played with different color parameters without success.
I need black border of box.
Yes, there examples to make custom checkbox.
In all drawable examples the normal box is visible inside of new shape.
And the drawable shape is narrow without text in `android:text=""`.

[image]

But why checkbox does not look okay in usual xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutBottom1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBottom1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAA"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:checked="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 76):

You can use the property

`android:buttonTint="what you want"` to set your checkbox border color.

Comment: This also sets the inside of the checkbox.  Not what you want!

Answer (score 45):

It's too late to answer but I would like to share what worked for me.
Paste below code. It would change the `CheckBox` border color and `textColor`

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#000</item>   <!-- normal border color change as you wish -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#000</item> <!-- activated color change as you wish -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF3F3C</item> <!-- checkbox text color -->
</style>
```

now in your **main_activity.xml** place below `CheckBox` code

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/check_agree"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="10dp"
          android:text="I agree"
          android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"/>   <!-- here apply your checkbox style -->
```

if above style not working then replace parent theme `parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"` with `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"`. Hope it would work.

Comment: It worked for me only if I inserted style items inside my main app style. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Did you try going through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288843/how-to-change-check-box-border-color-via-programmatically-in-android), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464143/android-set-color-of-checkbox) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854047/how-to-change-checkbox-color)?
And as per answering your question

```
But why checkbox does not look okay in usual xml
```

Thats because sometimes, the android graphical view is not able to render the custom views, in that case you need to run the code on the emulator or the device to test it out.

**UPDATE**
In case you dont want to use drawables, then you can also define the drawable shape in xml like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <solid android:color="#ffffff" >
        </solid>

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#ff0000" >
        </stroke>
<corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: In IntelliJ Idea's preview it looks okay. But not visible on Emulator and device. In your references they  change check mark color. But I'd like to change box border color

Comment: So you will need to have a slice for the box border. Slice as in an image which you would place in the drawable folder.

Comment: thanks, but not understood. What do you mean as a slice?

Comment: _Slice as in an image which you would place in the drawable folder._ Anyway forget that, and check my updated answer. Also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015463/defining-custom-checkbox-in-android).

Comment: I got text inside of text box trying your example. No. I need usual box with visible border.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either of them:

```
app:buttonTint="color code here"
```

or

```
android:buttonTint="color code here"
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers above worked for me, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448925/4687402) did. It suggests using a selector and applying it to the checkbox, which worked perfectly for me.

This does not explain the odd look of the checkbox as shown above, which is why I wouldn't mark this question as a duplicate, but I think it still works as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For API level < 21 you can use :

```
app:buttonTint="EEEEEE"
```

For API level >= 21 you can use :

```
android:buttonTint="EEEEEE"
```